# Tibco SPOTFIRE 7.5 how execute a custom script on load of analisys

Tags: javascript, ironpython, spotfire

I have to execute a script on load of an Spotfire analisys. 
I used this method:

**JScript**:

```js
$(function () {
 function executeScript() {
 $('#hiddenBtn input').click();
 }
$(document).ready(function(){executeScript()});
});
```

**HTML:**

```html
<Span style="display:none" id="hiddenBtn">
<SpotfireControl id="f8322a6109af43fb935ad6e7bcb1f1fc" /></span>
```

**IronPython script on HiddenButton:**

```
if Document.Properties["OpenedYet"] == False:
Document.Properties["OpenedYet"] = True
## Script you are trying to run on open here
```

**BUT**

the event $(document).ready() FIRE continuously and script was executed continuously.
I tried with $(document).load()  or $(window).load() but the event was never fired.
There is a way to execute a script **ONCE** on load?

Comment: when you say "on load," what's the context? is it in Spotfire Desktop (thick client) or Web Player (web browser)? if the latter, are users accessing it from a link in some kind of portal, or are they navigating the Spotfire library to open the file?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it might be better to use a hidden input field in order to change the document property and thus to trigger the python script.

Have a look [here](http://spotfired.blogspot.nl/2014/09/passing-javascript-values-to-document.html)...

and also [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_pageload.asp)